# How to style form controls as TextField in material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a form with many TextField elements.
In the form, there are other elements than TextField elements along with TextField elements.
The problem is that they look quite different from TextFields.
Take a look at the example below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-demo-forked-p8s87?file=/demo.js:488-520

As you can see, `InputLabel` doesn't work well with the element other than `Input`, while `FormLabel` doesn't look like the right alternative to `InputLabel`.
What I exactly want is to replace `Input` as `Link`, other elements staying the same as with `Input`. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Here is official doc https://material-ui.com/customization/components You can use themes, `CSS-in JSS` approach with @material-ui/styles lib or even CSS/LESS/SASS approach

Comment: Also, each component has a doc and a list of related components below https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/  Maybe you should try something like FormHelperText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Main difference with InputLabel  and FormLabel is that the InputLabel component adds an animation for us. The FormLabel component does not.
- There are four different inputs that we can use in Material-UI, InputBase Input OutlinedInput and FilledInput.
- The FormControl component in Material-UI is  a wrapper class for an input component. It is good to use a form control when you are using any input components in Material-UI, like a checkbox, radio button, or a switch.

Hence it is good practice to use FormControl with TextField if you don't need some animation on your input control in form like  "on focus", "leave focus" etc.

For more details understanding refere this [link](https://medium.com/geekculture/what-really-happens-when-you-use-the-textfield-component-in-material-ui-1e62652196f)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `Button`
You can use it like this:

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
```

1. 

```
<FormControl>
   <FormLabel shrink>hi</FormLabel>
   <Button color="primary" href="/link">hello</Button>
</FormControl>
```

2. 

```
<FormControl>
   <FormLabel shrink>hi</FormLabel>
   <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href="/link">hello</Button>
</FormControl>
```

3. 

```
<FormControl>
   <FormLabel shrink>hi</FormLabel>
   <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" href="/link">hello</Button>
</FormControl>
```

You can play around with `color` & `variant` but it'll give you a nice look for `Link`

Personally recommend you to check out [Rsuite Library](https://rsuitejs.com/components/overview) for other such UI components.